# How to use global state with reactQuery

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have one main page where Im calling GET endpoint with reactQuery.

```
const { data} = MyApi({
        //enabled: clientId != null
    }).get.useUserData(clientId);
```

It works OK.

But there is a need to read this data on some other indepedent function which is located in separate file (tranlsation.js)

What is the best way doing it with global state of reactQUery? (passing data object is not an option)

I tried to use in App.jsx wrapper like this:

```
import Translate from 'components/Translate';
import { QueryClient,QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';

const queryClient = new QueryClient();
const Routes = lazy(() => import('routes/routes'));

const App = () => {
    return (
        
                <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
                <NavigationBlocker>
                    <page-content id="content-main">
                        <Translate namespace="some">
                            {(t) => (
                                <section className="section pt-5 px-5 pb-0">
                                    <span className="page-title">{t('sometranslation')}</span>
                                </section>
                            )}
                        </Translate>
                        <Routes />
                    </page-content>
                </NavigationBlocker>
                <InitGlobalSwitcher />
                </QueryClientProvider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

in my translation.jsx Im trying to call the state using useQuery function:

```
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();
    const test = queryClient;
    console.log('test');
    console.log(test);
```

This code presents me the structure, but I cant find anywhere data.
[image]

**Solution that I didn't like:**

I tried with GLobalStateProvider component, which was using react context etc. and it works, but I would like to have global state functionality with react-query because Im already using this library.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const useTodos = (): UseTodos => {
  const {
    data: todos = [],
  } = useQuery(['todos'], fetchTodos);

  return {
    todos
  };
};
```

When you use a **useQuery** hook you need to provide a key, which will be used to store the query result in the cache.
The way you can retrieve this data is by doing:

```
const data = queryClient.getQueryData(queryKey) // ['todos'] in the example above.
```

UPDATE #1:
I tried to use `useQuery` and `QueryClient`:

```
import { useQuery, QueryClient} from '@tanstack/react-query';
...

const fetchTodos = () => {
    queryClient.setQueryData(['todos'], () => return { todos: 'tada' })
}
 
const MyPage = () => {
const { data } = useQuery(['todos'], fetchTodos ); // fetchTodos is either an API call or a function that will return data that will be stored under 'todos' key in the cache.
const queryData = queryClient.getQueryData('todos')
console.log(queryData);
}
```

The error Im getting noe is: `Cannot create property 'exact' on string 'todos' TypeError: Cannot create property 'exact' on string 'todos'`

Comment: Can you please make an example with my existing code? thanks

Comment: The code you've provided is not enough, or at least I don't see where you use react query for fetching data. Provide more information or upload it to github.

Comment: please take a look for my update #1, Im getting an  error.